# trying to point my domain to Azure website

Tags: azure, dns, cname

I'm trying to point my Israeli domain to my Azure website.
Did that before to a .com website, rather easily. However, I've been struggling with this for more than a day.
Following the instructions I added CNAME records as needed and also tried many other options as you can see in this image:
[image: SOA records of my website]

However, Azure keeps telling me that I am missing the needed record, as you can see in this image:

[image: Azure's error message]

(I've blanked things for security)

Can anyone see the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless I'm going blind! (its possible) that looks like it should do. it *could* be a typo in the bits that you've blanked out, or maybe a DNS issue - my first thought would be to verify that the cname is resolving, go to an online DNS checker and copy and paste from the azure site (just to be sure) - also make sure you're pointing it to the right azure site I chased that one for an hour once!

Comment: Try removing all the awverify parts, save and wait a few minutes before checking Azure again to get things set up. I usually don't use the awverify when working on development websites.

Comment: Thank you both. I have tried EVERYTHING! checked my dns using http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/. The result was that everything is fine. I also checked that there is no typo (million times). I have removed CNAME records like crazy trying all options with and without awverify records. Nothing seems to help. Can you think of something else? Is there a way for me to get Microsoft's support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me some time until I checked my records with this tool: `http://www.digwebinterface.com/`

When I checked my CNAME record: `awverify.????.co.il` I could notice that the result was awverify.???.azurewebsites.net.`???.co.il` the last part was an addition that I didn't know where it came from.

Apparently, as it turned out, with my registrar you have to end the value of the CNAME with a dot. If you don't do that it automatically adds your domain to the end. I don't know why it works this way, this was the first time I heard about it. Anyway, I added the dot and now everything works.